# Is it possible to add listview in fragment class?

Tags: android, android-fragments

**Here is my Fragment Class**

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class CommunityFragment extends Fragment {

    public CommunityFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_community, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

And Here is its plain **xml** wherein when i try to add the **listview tag** it occurs an error

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:divider="#9c9c9c"
    android:dividerHeight="5dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Here is the StackTrace**

```
    12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class <unknown>
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.CommunityFragment.onCreateView(CommunityFragment.java:36)
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:795)
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:998)
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1330)
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:417)
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  ... 21 more
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:483)
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1937)
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2780)
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:385)
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.widget.AdapterView.<init>(AdapterView.java:234)
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.widget.AbsListView.<init>(AbsListView.java:734)
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:141)
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:137)
12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  ... 24 more
```

Is it possible to add listview in fragment class?
Hoping someone might help me thank you!

Comment: Yes it is possible, anyway watching the stack trace the problem seems to be in your HomeFragment not in your CommunityFragment

Comment: this error is not for CommunityFragment please check your homefragment class where you deocoding image file...

Comment: edited the stack trace :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in following way-

```
public class CommunityFragment extends Fragment {

public CommunityFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_community, container, false);
View lv1 = rootView .findViewById(R.id.listView);

String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                    "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
               "Linux", "OS/2" };

ArrayAdapter<String> files = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), 
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
lv1.setAdapter(files);
return rootView;
        }
}
```

Comment: where did **R.id.listView** come from?

Comment: from above xml that you post.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to comment, but dot't have enough reputation... 
From your's stack trace it looks like to me the problem is in loading background of your listview, is this image maybe to large.

```
    ...
    Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:483)
    12-30 20:42:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
    ...
```

Try removing background drawable from your listview or replace it with simple color.